How do I assign defaults to a CLASS' properties at runtime?
Inspired by this question ("How to get default value for property using RTTI)
I thought of how to use the information in there to have a routine that could assign default values to all properties of a class on demand.
See my solution in the answer...

USES System.RTTI;

TYPE
  TPropertyHelper       = CLASS HELPER FOR TRttiProperty
                            FUNCTION    IsOrdinal : BOOLEAN; INLINE;
                            FUNCTION    Default : TValue;
                            FUNCTION    HasDefault : BOOLEAN;
                          END;

{ TPropertyHelper }

FUNCTION TPropertyHelper.Default : TValue;
  VAR
    DEF : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    IF Self IS TRttiInstanceProperty THEN
      DEF:=TRttiInstanceProperty(Self).Default
    ELSE
      DEF:=0;
    Result:=TValue.FromOrdinal(PropertyType.Handle,DEF)
  END;

FUNCTION TPropertyHelper.HasDefault : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=IsOrdinal AND (Self IS TRttiInstanceProperty) AND (Default<>INTEGER($80000000))
  END;

FUNCTION TPropertyHelper.IsOrdinal : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=PropertyType.IsOrdinal
  END;

PROCEDURE AssignDefaults(CONST [ref] O : TObject ; IncludeInherited : BOOLEAN = TRUE);
  TYPE
    TRttiProperties     = TArray<TRttiProperty>;

  VAR
    CTX                 : TRttiContext;
    ClassType           : TRttiType;
    Properties          : TRttiProperties;
    P                   : TRttiProperty;

  BEGIN
    CTX:=TRttiContext.Create;
    ClassType:=CTX.GetType(O.ClassType);
    IF IncludeInherited THEN Properties:=ClassType.GetProperties ELSE Properties:=ClassType.GetDeclaredProperties;
    FOR P IN Properties DO IF P.IsWritable AND P.HasDefault THEN P.SetValue(O,P.Default)
  END;


How do you detect if a property has a default? So far, I've noticed that the ordinal value of the default is $8000000 but that can't be the right way, surely?

If I remember correctly I stumbled upon this too a while ago and It turned out that this is just the way Borland (back in the olden days) implemented it, and nobody later on bothered to change it. But my memory is rather hazy. I think I even wrote a bug report (in the old QM-System, now defunct).
